# Passing column to convert to timezone value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using `to_utc_timestamp` to convert timestamp to UTC time. I have Date time in one column and timezone in another column when I pass time zone it says column not callable:

```
data_frame.withColumn(‘target_date’, to_utc_timestamp(data_frame.doj_date, data_frame.doj_tz))
```

> data_frame.doj_tz - Column object is not callable

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass a column object to a `pyspark` function if the function does not expect a column object as an argument.  In this case, `to_utc_timestamp` expects a string representing the timezone and you are providing a column object, which is why you are getting this error.

The workaround would be to use `expr` in `withColumn` instead:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as func

data_frame.withColumn('target_date', func.expr("to_utc_timestamp(doj_date, doj_tz)"))
```